# Adding Controls to Control inside of a Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-controls, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer

I am attempting to make a complete custom TabControl.

So far my code works perfectly, however when I'm viewing my TabControl in the Visual Studio designer, I cannot add Controls into the TabPage Control which is inside of the TabControl. When attempted, it just places the control on top of the TabControl.

Unless you are adding controls to the TabPage via programming it by hand, that is, not using Visual Studio's Designer, using the TabControl is pointless.

[PasteBin Link to my Control's Code](https://pastebin.com/Z49UFkAd)

Here are images of the tab control with different tabs selected:
[image: Tab Page 1 Selected]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/0775c34f525c9c94e8adf5072357901c.png))</sub>

[image: Tab Page 2 Selected]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/b8a759d3490a01128c8503577c6d709d.png))</sub>

As you can see from the above images, the button is not placed into the tab page's control collection, as it floats above the tab control.

Comment: probably a limitation of the windows forms designer. Using wpf-> xaml would probably work like you would want it though...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I honestly can't switch this project to WPF. I know it isn't a limitation of the windows forms designer, but more so a flaw with my programming.

Comment: Can you post your code of what you have tried?

Comment: You'll have to create your own designer class, like TabControl does.  Derive it from ParentControlDesigner, it implements the basic design-time support for a control that supports nested controls.  Getting the active tab-page to switch at design-time is the trickier part, have a look at the TabControlDesigner class with a good decompiler for guidance.

Comment: Ok so if I remove the custom AbideTabPage designer, it works, but I can also move and resize the tab page in the designer, which is not desired. The standard Panel designer must have enough functionality to allow the results I expected. Now to customize this designer....

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Tabcontrol from Design Toolbox in form and place the controls as you want.Then add the piece of code provided below to your code this will work.

Suppose you have custom class as Use this code write the Constructor as given below.

```
 internal class MyCustomTabControl
 {
    public MyCustomTabControl(TabControl tabControlPassed)
        : base()
    {
        this.tabcontrol = tabControlPassed;
    }
    TabControl tabcontrol;
 }
```

In the main form Initialization call MyCustomTabControl initialization after InitializeComponent() method. Pass the `this.tabControl1` while initializing Custom tabcontrol.

```
 public partial class TabForm : Form
 {       
    public TabForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCustomTabControl customTab = new MyCustomTabControl(this.tabControl1);
    }
 }
```

:)